# 特定の行を抽出し、出力する方法を知りたいです。

Tags: python

Pythonに触れて3日目の初心者です...
以下のような、一分ごとに記録されたcsv時系列データがあります。

1列目:日付(mm/dd/yy)
2列目:時間(hh:mm:ss)
3〜12列目(各データ)

12/27/18     08:32:14    960.65    0    33.1    0.1376    1.94    75.8    307.5    2.77    11.08    0.1368
12/27/18     08:33:14    960.55    0    35.6    0.1368    1.94    75.8    15.4    0.25    1.51    0.1376
12/27/18     08:34:14    960.65    0    36.9    0.1368    1.913    75.5    355.2    1.51    4.53    0.1376
・
・
・
01/21/19     08:55:14    958.95    0    -888.9    0.0214    0.301    57.3    308.9    2.52    6.3    0.0228
01/21/19     08:56:14    959.15    0    -888.9    0.0214    0.163    57.7    205    2.01    5.54    0.0228
01/21/19     08:57:14    959.15    0    -888.9    0.0214    0.163    57.7    282.2    2.01    4.78    0.0228

データの期間は12/27〜1/21なのですが、これを日ごとにデータを抽出してcsvに出力するプログラムを組みたいです。
例として、下の画像は月ごとですが、このような形で日ごとに出力されるのが理想です。

[image: 1]
pandasを使用しプログラムを組んでみたのですが、どうもうまく動きません。
稚拙な説明で申し訳ありませんが、お分かりになる方にご教授いただけると幸いです...
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 実際に書いたプログラムを提示しながら、「どこがどううまく動かないのか」を詳しく説明してもらうと回答も付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/184288

Answer (score 1):

次の条件を補完して、以下のようになるでしょう。

- 入力ファイル名は仮に 'data.csv'
- 入力側/出力側の両方のデータにヘッダ行は無し
- データの区切りはタブコード

異常なデータやエラーへの対処は省いています。

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

infilename = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(infilename, header=None, sep='\t', names=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
date_list = list(df['A'].unique())
for date_str in date_list:
    outfilename = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv'
    ds = df[df['A'].isin([date_str])]
    ds.to_csv(outfilename, header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
```

---

マルチポスト先の回答の方が簡潔ですね。ただ出力ファイル名は当方のが良さそうです。
パクッて組み合わせると以下になるでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

infilename = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(infilename, header=None, sep='\t')
for date_str, daily_data in df.groupby(0):
    outfilename = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv'
    daily_data.to_csv(outfilename, header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
```

他にこの辺の記事が、csv の読み書き時の使い方を詳しく解説しているでしょう。
[詳説Pandasのread_csvとread_table関数の使い方](https://deepage.net/features/pandas-readcsv-deep.html)
[Pandasのto_csv関数を使ってCSVファイルに書き出す方法](https://deepage.net/features/pandas-tocsv-light.html)

同サイトで groupby の使い方記事です。
[Pandasのgroupbyを使った要素をグループ化して処理をする方法](https://deepage.net/features/pandas-groupby.html)